# Why $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{2\cdot4}+\dots+\frac{1}{n\cdot(n+2)}}=\frac{3}{4}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\ge1}^{\infty}=\bigg\{\cfrac{1}{1\cdot3}+\cfrac{1}{2\cdot4}+\dots+\cfrac{1}{n\cdot(n+2)}\bigg\}$. Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}$.

I write:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n\cdot(n+2)}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2+2n}}\approx\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\cfrac{1}{n^2}}$$

I put some values of $n$ for finding a pattern:
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & \text{1}&\text{2}&\text{3}&\text{4}\\
\hline
\sum &\cfrac{1}{3}&\cfrac{11}{24}&\cfrac{21}{40}&\cfrac{17}{30}
\end{array}
$$

... but no hope.
I know that the limit/series converges, because $\forall n\in\mathbb N^*$:

1. $\{a_n\}$ is increasing by the test of monothony : $a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\cfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+3)}>0$
2. $\{a_n\}$ is bounded : $0\le a_1=\frac{1}{3}\le a_2=\frac{11}{24}\le \dots \le a_n \le1$

Wolfram says that the summation can be written as follows:
$$\cfrac{3}{4}-\cfrac{2n+3}{2(n+1)(n+2)}$$
How did it end up at this formula? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, yes! My mistake, thank you!

Comment: [Pronic numbers](http://oeis.org/A005563) for more...

Answer (score 7):

Telescope! Note that $$ \frac1{n(n+2)}=\frac12\cdot\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+2}\right)$$

Comment: You saved me with these partial fractions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{n + 2}}&=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 3}}
={\Psi\pars{3} - \Psi\pars{1} \over 3 - 1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\Psi\pars{z}$ is the $\it digamma$ function. By using the identity
$\Psi\pars{z} = 1/\pars{z - 1} + \Psi\pars{z - 1}$ we'll get:
$$
\Psi\pars{3} = \half + \Psi\pars{2} = \half + 1 + \Psi\pars{1} = {3 \over 2} + \Psi\pars{1}
$$
We replace this result in $\pars{1}$:
$$
\color{#00f}{\large\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{n + 2}} = {3 \over 4}}
$$

Comment: This is very elegant for sure but, using partial fractions, it is immediate to see that the result is (1/2) (1 + 1/2) = 3/4. I really like the general usage you have of the digamma function.

Comment: I like gamma's in general. Indeed, I was trying to find something like 'telescopic' but I didn't see it. Thanks.

Comment: @Felix, can you explain why the equation (1) in your answer holds? I'm not so familiar with the digamma function that I can recognize this as "trivial". I would upvote your answer if you could explain this, because it seems that the 1 and 3 return in your equation and that there is a more general approach to similar sums.